# Why can't I connect to my server from within a docker container?

Tags: python, docker, flask, server, python-3.8

I can can connect from outside the container (i.e. by typing `localhost:5000` into a browser, or when running the same client code regularly from outside docker). I can also run my client when I replace `http://localhost:5000/` in my client code with whatever url comes up when I start the server, like for example "Running on `http://172.17.0.2:5000/` (Press CTRL+C to quit)"

server.py:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

client.py:

```
import requests
response = requests.get("http://localhost:5000/")
print(response.text)
```

server dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8.10
WORKDIR ./server
COPY ./app/server.py .
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENV FLASK_APP=server.py
CMD ["python", "server.py"]
```

client dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8.10
WORKDIR ./client
COPY ./app/client.py .
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python", "client.py"]
```

commands I use:
`docker build ./server -t server`
`docker run -p 5000:5000 server`

followed by: `docker build ./client -t client`
`docker run client`

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 3, in <module>
    response = requests.get("http://localhost:5000/")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fa25d245a30>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's because "localhost:5000" in the client script is pointing to it's own port 5000, not the port 5000 of the server. You could try the docker bridge IP instead 172.17.0.2:5000

Comment: Best practice is to `docker network create` a network, then `docker run --net` both containers on the same network, and their `docker run --name` will be usable as host names.  Or, if you run this stack under Docker Compose, it does all of that setup for you.  The linked questions (and @HiranChaudhuri's similar answer) have more details.

Answer (score 1):

You are connecting server and client via the url http://localhost:5000, which only works if the processes are running on the same host.
Next you start each of them in their own container, but docker will give each of them a different network namespace - you should assume each container is a separate machine. Localhost on one will not be the same as localhost for the other.
In the end the perceived result "connection refused" is to be expected as in the client's container that port is not used for listening.

To get out of that situation:

- create a network using `docker network create ...`
- run both containers by connecting them to the network by using `docker run --network ...` (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings)
- change your URL into something like `http://<server container name>:5000`